# phpMyDataGrid - Button to copy row to clipboard

Tags: php, mysql

I am using phpMyDataGrid as a MySQL editor / viewer so I can edit and view my database. phpMyDataGrid is great but I would like the have the option of copying rows so I can quickly paste data in to Excel. Data is already indented as a table so they paste accordingly in Excel.

I created a picture of what I desire - A clickable box for each row with a row at the top which selects all rows in view and a button at the bottom which would copy these selected rows to my clipboard. Programatically speaking, is this possible to do?

[image: Img]

I am using example 10 from phpMyDataGrid. Link is here: http://www.gurusistemas.com/_guru/samples2007/sample10.php

Know if this is possible would be awesome, better yet if someone could provide some sample code that would allow this to happen would be even better. Thanks!

Comment: you are better off just grabbing a mysql client that can do that feature by default. MySQL workbench will do exactly what you want: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: @MarkBerube I'm not sure that that's a remotely practical suggestion :-(

Comment: @MarkBerube I dont think it does, can you clearfy the features it provides that does this? It seems MySQL workbench would only make what I am trying to do more time consuming.

Comment: @Strawberry your comment is not very helpful :( . If you have a better suggestion than a MySQL client like workbench it would be helpful to the poster to share it.

Comment: @Hugh What you would do is make a connection to your MySQL server directly with the client, open the database and select table you want to export. After the query has completed there's a few ways to can export it into Excel. Direct copying you would right click on the rows copy(tab seperated) and paste directly into Excel. You can also save your query as a CSV file that can be opened by Excel.